# Features conflicts when field bases are used by other feature

Tags: features

I recently downloaded the Features module and was so glad over how smoothly I now can export functionality from dev to prod. But now when I'm trying to create a second feature I'm getting conflicts because I already used a lot of the same field bases in my first feature.

What can I do to resolve this? Are you not suppose to be able to use the same fields in different features? It doesn't seem right that I should have to define as many fields for "body text" that I have features, or image fields for that matter. Those fields could and should be shared right?

What are my options here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have two Features, and one field that is used in both Features, then you only need to export the field base ONCE.

This is why I generally have a "controller" Feature that contains field *bases*, update hooks etc, and then for every other Feature I export the field *instance*, and then add a dependency on my controller feature.

Basically, you are right - you don't need to export the field bases every time, just export them once and then add dependencies.

Comment: ^ This seems a bit ropey, if you need any further clarification please let me know and I'll see if I can expand.

Comment: Yes I just started doing something like this. I'm now removing the field bases from my created feature, and adding them in a new "Master field bases feature", which I'll be adding as a dependency on future features that share fields.

This is what you mean right? Also, this seems like a better idea than not defining the field bases in a "master feature", since then future feature dependencies will be all over the place.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I do.  My "controller" Feature always serves other purposes as well though.  For example, if during my feature development, I change some module settings, I put them in a `hook_update_N` implementation in the controller feature's `.install` file. All of my dependencies are resolved with the controller feature, and all of my "sub-features" depend on the controller.  This means that all module dependencies are resolved in one single place, as opposed to 5/6/different Features....does that make sense?

Comment: While we are on this issue, how do I set up my dependencies to the "master feature"? I have now created a master feature with the base fields, and my other feature holds the fields instances instead. Do I add dependencies myself somewhere or does this work automaticly? I dont see any options.

Comment: When you create/rebuild your Feature, there is a fieldset for Dependencies, which is just a list of modules.  Any modules you check here will be added as a dependency. Some are added automatically (as you've probably seen when adding Views, Contexts, Panels etc. You can also manually edit the `.info` file if that's easier for you. Remember, although they're called Features, they're just modules at the end of the day :)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with hook_update_N. What does it do? How does that work? I'm more of a designer than a coder so if you can explain in an even simpler way, that might do it for me :)

Comment: Ah, that's a completely different question I'm afaid. Two good places to start are the documentation for [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) or the [tag:hook-update-n] tag on this site :)

Comment: I didn't see the master field feature/module in the dependencies list because I hadn't checked either features. When I checked them both, and clicked recreate on my feature, the master feature was added automatically in the dependencies list. So it looks right now I think!